# Invisible div over div does not work in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, invisible

I'm trying to create an invisible div, over the facebook comments plugin in order to disable the plugin's functionality in an Editor View. This invisible div works in all browsers except IE8. How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="coveriframe"></div>   
    <div data-bind-component="fbml: fbml">(RENDER JS COMMENTS VIA KO)</div>
</div>
```

**Try in IE8:**

http://jsfiddle.net/pkbz4/19/

- The above code works in ALL other Major browsers. WTF Microsoft?

Stylesheet:

```
    #container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    #navi, 
    #coveriframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    #coveriframe {
        z-index: 10;
   }
```

Comment: did you try setting the `background: transparent;` what do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: maybe this helps? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360131/how-to-fix-absolute-positioning-in-ie8)

Comment: THe user can still interact with the bottom div. I don't want this. I want coveriframe to cover the bottom div, container

Comment: IE8 doesn't understand `100%` sometimes, can an exact pixel `width`/`height` be used?

Comment: Also, what about `top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;` instead of just `top: 0; left: 0;`?

Comment: A side note - So you are trying to disable functionality using CSS? Anyone who knows how could just go in and remove the overlay div, and then be able to interact with the comments again - is this really a good solution (not that I have another to offer...)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've done this several times in IE8. The solution that works for me is to assign a background color to the div and then set opacity to 0. IE8 then recognizes the div as "existing" above the rest of the content.  I also find setting `position: absolute` and all four directions to 0 is more reliable than 100% width and height. Like this:

```
#coveriframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 3007;
  background: #fff;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Here's my update to your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkbz4/21/

Comment: Thats hours of my life I will never get back. Thanks for the IE hack man!

Comment: No worries. I learned this trick from Firebug Lite's handling of IE in this same situation (for the Element Inspector). That took a while to track down!

Answer (score 4):

**[CSS Specification says:](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property)**

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to 'auto'.

Basically, In older versions of IE (including IE8) percentage heights are based on the height of the parent element. If the parent element doesn't have an explicit height, the percentage is ignored and set to Auto (in this case, 0px).

So, to fix this, you'll either want to explicitly set the height/width of #coveriframe or its parent. One thing you could try is setting the height of **html** and **body** to 100% (I'm assuming those are the parent elements).

```
html, body { height:100%; }

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#navi,
#coveriframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#coveriframe {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Why set the background of `#coveriframe` to `transparent`? By default, the background of a `div` is `transparent`.

Answer (score 1):

why did you want to do in javascript and it works well in all browsers, I'll let my example I hope you work:

-----------------DIV-----------------

> `<div id="div1" style="display: block;">
>               <div class="mainbody">
>                   <br />
>   </div></div>`

-----------------JavaScript----------------

```
    function showHideDiv(divX) {

        if (divX == "1") {
            document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility = "hidden";

    }
```

-----------------button HTML----------------

`<li><a href="#cuenta" onclick="showHideDiv(0)">click_Aqui</a></li>`

Comment: Its a good solution, but not for my use case. I need the user to be able to see it, but not interact with it. Its a hack.

Comment: It would be great if IE worked as all other browsers on earth work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that internet explorer up to ie9 doesn't recognize the mouse hover when hovered over a transparent background. Zach Shipley answer offers a good solutions.

But in case you want to add a border or an element to the transparent div or text the easiest way of doing this is by adding a 1px transparent png as background.

```
#coveriframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 3007;
  background-image: url("pixel-transparent.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are putting fixed height & width to that `DIV`.

As Shaquin Trifonoff mentioned above sometimes `100%` or any length in `%` may not work on`IE8`. Always I am trying to avoid `%` in such situation.

Code snippet :-

```
html,body{ //This makes your page expandable as per screen resolution 
 height:100%;
}

#your-hide-div{
  height:100px;
  width: 100px;
  display:block;
}
```