# Why the SPANs inside a DIV not clickable

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a ribbon at the top of the page which has some DIV inside:

```
<div id="headerRibbon">
    <span id="socialIcons">
        <a title="WMED Homepage" href="Default.aspx"><img src="theImages/wmlogo.png" width="219" height="47" alt="WMED Homepage" title="WMED Homepage" /></a>
    </span>
    <span id="socialIcons2">
        <table cellpadding=0>
            <tr>
                <td id="socialIconTD"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/"><img alt="LikeFacebook" title="LikeFacebook" src="theImages/facebook.png" class="fbClass" width="35" height="35" /></a></td>
                <td id="socialIconTD"><a href="http://twitter.com/"><img alt="FollowTwitter" title="FollowTwitter" src="theImages/twitter.png" class="twClass" id="tw" width="35" height="35" /></a></td>
                <td id="socialIconTD"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/"><img alt="ConnectLinkedIn" title="ConnectLinkedIn" src="theImages/linkedin.png" class="liClass" id="li" width="35" height="35" /></a></td>
                <td id="socialIconTD"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/"><img alt="WatchYouTube" title="WatchYoutube" src="theImages/youtube.png" class="ytClass" id="yt" width="35" height="35" /></a></td>
                <td id="socialIconTD"><a href="http://pinterest.com/"><img alt="PinPinterest" title="Pin Pinterest" src="theImages/pinterest.png" class="ptClass" id="pt" width="35" height="35" /></a></td>
                <td id="socialIconTD"><a href="https://plus.google.com/"><img alt="+1Google Plus" title="+1Google Plus" src="theImages/googleplus.png" class="gpClass" id="gp" width="35" height="35" /></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </span>
    <span id="tSearch">
        <form method="post" action="http://www.google.com">
            <input name="" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search WMED" />
        </form>
    </span>
</div>
```

Which works great in IE11/FF/Chrome but not in IE8. In IE8, it seems there is an overlay which is on top of all the icons.

In IE11/FF/Chrome it shows like this, allowing me to click on the social icons and click on the logo on the left and also enter text in the search box:

[image]

In IE8 there is an overlay which causes the everything to be below and I am not able to click on any of the social icons/logo or enter any text into the search box:

[image]

Here is the CSS:

```
#headerRibbon {
    position: fixed;
    background: url('../theImages/bg_80_w.png');
    height: 62px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 18;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
}
#socialIcons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 40px;
    z-index: 5;
}
#socialIcons2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    z-index: 5;
    height: 62px;
    top: 20%;
}
#tSearch {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -5;
    right: 10px;
}
#tSearch input[type="text"] {
    background: url(theImages/search-white.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #135C9D;
    border: 0 none;
    font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    color: #d7d7d7;
    width:150px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    }

#tSearch input[type="text"]:focus {
    background: url(theImages/search-dark.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #187DD2;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 175px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(208, 208, 208, 0.8), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(208, 208, 208, 0.8), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(208, 208, 208, 0.8), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

If I remove the `tSearch` span, it shows up just fine.

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Using tables for layout is not recommended. Other more flexible and yet robust solutions are available. You also seen to be using `<span>` where a block level element would be more appropriate. http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you declared a DOCTYPE?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Yes I have. It works in all browsers except IE8 :/ Some reason the `tSearch` span is causing the issue but can't understand why.

Comment: Ie8 and absolute positioning = headache. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360131/how-to-fix-absolute-positioning-in-ie8 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326511/ie8-ignores-absolute-positioning-and-marginauto

Comment: Why is it if i remove the entire code inside the span, span included it's fine?

Comment: I believe as @paulie_D points out <span> is an inline element and <div> is a block element. Change it to a div. Also, IE8 only has about 6% of over all browser share. Do you really need it to work in IE8? http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201402-201402-bar

Comment: I changed it to `div` and it still having the same issue. Unfortunately our company uses IE8 due to application constraints so if our stakeholders can't see it then it won't work :/

Comment: The only thing is... JSFIDDLE doesn't work in IE8 and that is where the issue is...

Comment: Well, you could try using draft mode for IE8. See the bug has been closed here: https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/311

Comment: I just tested something out and it seems the `<form></form>` is what is causing the issue. Maybe I have to set the size of the form?

Comment: I was able to resolve it. Because I already had a form top level it was conflicting with my form. I ended up using one form for all. Accepted and Upvoted. Thanks!